# Tile up to drywall on outside corner

Tags: drywall, tile

I'm getting ready to put up tile on this shower wall, the rough stud wall will have drywall on its face when I'm done. I'm having a tough time figuring out how to connect the two surfaces at a right angle. I picked up schluter tile trim and I could put that on the outside of the tile, but then what would be advised for the drywall and? What I put wooden trim on the face of the drywall overlapping the tile trim? Are there other ways to do this? Thanks for any advice[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try a tile edge nosing.

Something like :
[image]

You'd tile over the top part, and the lower part would wrap around the drywall at the corner:

[image]